# Glassfish grizzly thread consuming 100% CPU time

Tags: glassfish, glassfish-3, grizzly

We recently noticed an issue where our Glassifish server, after running successfully for several hours, would suddenly peg one of the CPUs at 100%.  Our application becomes unresponsive during this time.  After restarting, the problem will eventually happen again (usually after several hours).

I ran this command to see what the threads were doing:

asadmin generate-jvm-report --type=thread

In the resulting output, one thread looked highly suspicious (consuming orders of magnitude more CPU time than any other thread):

Thread Execution Information:

---

```
Thread "Grizzly-kernel-thread(1)" thread-id: 27 thread-state: RUNNABLE Running in native
    at: sun.nio.ch.WindowsSelectorImpl$SubSelector.poll0(Native Method)
    at: sun.nio.ch.WindowsSelectorImpl$SubSelector.poll(WindowsSelectorImpl.java:273)
    at: sun.nio.ch.WindowsSelectorImpl$SubSelector.access$400(WindowsSelectorImpl.java:255)
    at: sun.nio.ch.WindowsSelectorImpl.doSelect(WindowsSelectorImpl.java:136)
    at: sun.nio.ch.SelectorImpl.lockAndDoSelect(SelectorImpl.java:69)
    at: sun.nio.ch.SelectorImpl.select(SelectorImpl.java:80)
    at: com.sun.grizzly.TCPSelectorHandler.select(TCPSelectorHandler.java:513)
    at: com.sun.grizzly.SelectorHandlerRunner.doSelect(SelectorHandlerRunner.java:190)
    at: com.sun.grizzly.SelectorHandlerRunner.run(SelectorHandlerRunner.java:132)
    at: java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
    at: java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
    at: java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
```

Thread Synchronization Statistics:

---

Number of times this thread was blocked (to enter/reenter a Monitor): 4,520

Number of times this thread waited for a notification (i.e. it was in WAITING or TIMED_WAITING state): 0

Total CPU time for this thread: 2,753 seconds 703,125,000 nanoseconds.

User-level CPU time for this thread: 2,753 seconds 703,125,000 nanoseconds.

Object Monitors currently held or requested by this thread: []

Ownable Synchronizers (e.g. ReentrantLock and ReentrantReadWriteLock) held by this thread: []

We are running Glassfish 3.1.2.2 on Windows Server 2008 R2 Enterprise.  Any insights into what is going are highly appreciated.

Comment: which jdk are you using?

Comment: We're using JDK version 1.6.0_37.

Answer (score 1):

It may be JDK issue. In Grizzly there is a workaround for empty selector spin issue, which occur on Linux with earlier versions of JDK 6. But it is not applied on Windows.

Can I ask you to create either Glassfish or Grizzly issue?

Comment: Ok.  I've submitted Glassfish issue 19444: http://java.net/jira/browse/GLASSFISH-19444